# How to remove Windows border from WPF UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

To preface this question, I am working on coding the back end of an application whose UI was put together by someone else (I believe using Blend).  The application consists of a series of "Screens," whose root element in XAML is "UserControl".  There is no use of the "Window" tag anywhere in the source.

What I want to do is remove the Windows border that is added to the outside edge of the application when I run the program.  The border currently consists of forward/backward buttons like a web browser, and an X button to close.

All I can find from searches are instructions to add

```
WindowStyle="None"
```

to the

```
<Window>
```

element.  But of course, I don't have one of those, and WindowStyle is not a property of UserControl.  Anyone know how to accomplish this with UserControl root elements?

**Edit:**  The StartupUri for the application is

```
this.StartupUri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/WpfPrototype1.Screens;Component/Screen_1.xaml");
```

the file it points to does not have a Window tag.

Comment: A `Window` must be created somewhere, you need to modify that.\

Comment: Look harder for a Window object :)

Comment: Well I searched the entire solution using find in files with parameter "</window>" and "<window", but zero results.  Could it be hidden from that search somehow?

Comment: @Tevis maybe the window is being created in code.

Comment: Any idea where that might be?  I'm drawing a blank here...

Comment: Also Window window = Window.GetWindow(this) returns null

Comment: 1. In your Application tag in App.xaml, is there a property StartupUri? If so, that is pointing to your "Window". 2. Check App.xaml.cs. Is there an override method for OnStartUp? If so, navigate thru the code and try to work out if it is creating any window objects there. A dead giveaway would be someobject.Show() or ShowDialog()

Comment: I added the StartupUri to the post, but it just seems to point to a xaml file with a UserControl tag

Comment: This should find the main Window in WPF `var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above it seems your `MainWindow` is created dynamically somewhere, however you can use the `Application` class to get the applications `MainWindow`.

```
var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

And you can then set your border style from there

Example:

```
private void RemoveBorder()
{
    var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    if (mainWindow != null)//should never be
    {
        mainWindow.WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None; // removes top bar (icon, title, close buttons etc)
        mainWindow.AllowsTransparency = true; //removes the border around the outside
    }
}
```